# Sum consecutive hours when condition is met

Tags: r, dplyr, timestamp, lubridate

I have a dataframe that has a timestamp and a numeric variable, the data is recorded once every hour. Ultimately, I'd life to know the mean number of hours that the variable is at or below a certain value.  For example, what is the average number of hours that `var1` is at or below 4? There are missing timestamps in the dataframe, so if the time is not consecutive the sum needs to restart.

In the example data frame the columns `HoursBelow5` and `RunningGroup` were generated 'by hand', if I could create these columns programmatically, I could filter to remove the `RunningGroup`s that were associate with `var1` values greater than 4 and then use `dplyr::slice` to get the maximum `HoursBelow5` per group. I could then find the mean of these values.

So, in this approach I would need to create the restarting cumulative sum `HoursBelow5`, which restarts when the condition `var1`<5 is not met, or when the timestamp is not consecutive hours. I could then use `ifelse` statements to create the `RunningGroup` variable. Is this possible? I may be lacking the jargon to find the procedure. `Cumsum` and `lag` seemed promising, but I have yet to construct a procedure that does the above.

Or, there may be a smarter way to do this using the timestamp.

edit: result incorporating code from answer below

```
df1 <- df %>%
  group_by(group = data.table::rleid(var1 > 4), 
           group1 = cumsum(ts - lag(ts, default = first(ts)) > 3600)) %>%
  mutate(temp = row_number() * (var1 <= 4)) %>%
  ungroup() %>%
  filter(var1 <= 4) %>% 
  select(ts, var1, temp)

df2 <- df1 %>% mutate(temp2 = ifelse(temp==1, 1, 0), 
                      newgroup = cumsum(temp2))

df3 <- df2 %>% group_by(newgroup) %>% slice(which.max(temp))
mean(df3$temp)

# example dataframe with desired output columns to then get actual output
df <- structure(list(ts = structure(c(-2208967200, -2208963600, -2208960000, 
-2208956400, -2208952800, -2208949200, -2208945600, -2208942000, 
-2208938400, -2208934800, -2208931200, -2208927600, -2208924000, 
-2208913200, -2208909600, -2208906000, -2208902400, -2208898800, 
-2208895200, -2208891600, -2208888000, -2208884400, -2208880800, 
-2208877200, -2208852000, -2208848400, -2208844800, -2208841200, 
-2208837600, -2208834000, -2208830400, -2208826800, -2208823200, 
-2208819600, -2208816000, -2208812400, -2208808800, -2208805200, 
-2208801600), class = c("POSIXct", "POSIXt"), tzone = ""), var1 = c(1L, 
3L, 4L, 5L, 4L, 3L, 5L, 6L, 7L, 8L, 3L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 
2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 4L, 4L, 3L, 9L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 
5L, 3L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 3L), HoursBelow5 = c(1L, 2L, 3L, 0L, 1L, 
2L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 7L, 8L, 
9L, 10L, 11L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 7L, 0L, 1L, 2L, 
3L, 4L, 5L), RunningGroup = c(1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 
6L, 7L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 
10L, 11L, 12L, 12L, 12L, 12L, 12L, 12L, 12L, 13L, 14L, 14L, 14L, 
14L, 14L), NotContinuous = c("", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", 
"", "", "", "", "", "NC", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", 
"", "NC", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", 
"")), row.names = c(NA, -39L), class = "data.frame")
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One way could using `dplyr` and `data.table::rleid` could be

```
library(dplyr)

df %>%
   group_by(group = data.table::rleid(var1 > 4), 
            group1 = cumsum(ts - lag(ts, default = first(ts)) > 3600)) %>%
   mutate(temp = row_number() * (var1 <= 4)) %>%
   ungroup() %>%
   select(ts, var1, HoursBelow5, temp)

#   ts                   var1 HoursBelow5  temp
#   <dttm>              <int>       <int> <int>
# 1 1900-01-01 12:46:46     1           1     1
# 2 1900-01-01 13:46:46     3           2     2
# 3 1900-01-01 14:46:46     4           3     3
# 4 1900-01-01 15:46:46     5           0     0
# 5 1900-01-01 16:46:46     4           1     1
# 6 1900-01-01 17:46:46     3           2     2
# 7 1900-01-01 18:46:46     5           0     0
# 8 1900-01-01 19:46:46     6           0     0
# 9 1900-01-01 20:46:46     7           0     0
#10 1900-01-01 21:46:46     8           0     0
# … with 29 more rows
```

`temp` column is the one which was generated programmatically and `HoursBelow5` is kept as it is for comparison purposes. If you also need `RunningGroup` you could use `group` and `group1` together.

Comment: How can I create a new group that uses `group` and `group1` to create groups that account for the non-continuous hours? I think that is needed to arrive at the desired answer.

I'd like to do something like ` df2 %>% group_by(new_group) %>% slice(which.max(temp))` to find the hours elapsed for each consecutive group. Currently neither `group` nor `group1` would capture this, e.g., look at `group` 5.

Comment: If possible a little help understanding `group1 = cumsum(ts - lag(ts, default = first(ts)) > 3600))` would be much appreciated.

Comment: I think this works for the 'newgroup', assuming `df2` is the result of the above `
df2 <- df1 %>% mutate(temp2 = ifelse(temp==1, 1, 0), 
                      newgroup = cumsum(temp2)) `

Comment: @nofunsally `group1 = cumsum(ts - lag(ts, default = first(ts)) > 3600))` is used to account for consecutive hours. 3600 is number of seconds in an hour. So a new group is created every time the previous entry has a duration greater than 3600.